# No se como hacer este ejercicio, es de arreglos

Tags: java, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package Ejercicios_trabajo_final;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejer_11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int i=0,l=0,c=0,j=0,a=0;
        
        int[] A = new int [2];
        int[] B = new int [2];
        int[] Xi = new int [2+1];
        
        while(i <= 2-1){
            System.out.print("A["+(i+1)+"]: ");
            A[i]= entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.print("B["+(i+1)+"]: ");
            B[i]= entrada.nextInt();
            i++;
        }    
            
       while (l<= 2-1){
           if ((((A[l])^2)- ((B[l])^2))>0){
                Xi[l] = A[l] + B[l];
               while(l <= 2){
               c = c + Xi[l];
               l++;
            }
        System.out.println("La sumatoria de Y es :"+c);
            }else if((((A[l])^2) - ((B[l])^2))==0){
                Xi[l] = (A[l] - 2) * B[l];
               while(l <= 2){
               a = a + Xi[l];
               l++;
            }
        System.out.println("La sumatoria de Y es :"+a);
            }
            else if((((A[l])^2) - ((B[l])^2))<0){
                Xi[l] = A[l] + B[l] - 5;
               while(l <= 2){
               j = j + Xi[l];
               l++;
            }
             System.out.println("La sumatoria de Y es :"+j); 
            }   
            i++;
        } 
        }
    }
```

Necesito que alguien me guié para hacerlo, no doy sinceramente, no me sale nada, gracias de antemano, llevo pocos días programando y no tengo muy clara la idea de los arreglos, y mi profesor no es que explique muy bien, he hecho lo que pude, pero me sale.

Answer (score 2):

Primero: Lees del teclado el numero total del sumatorio N.

Segundo: Por cada iteración, como te indican en el problema, recibes dos variables que son a y b.

En funcion del resultado de a2 - b2, varía la formula con la que calculas xi.

Finalmente "y" es la suma de todas las xi y que has ido acumulando a lo largo del bucle.

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProblemaStackOverFlow {
    
     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int N = entrada.nextInt();
        
        int y = 0;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            int a = entrada.nextInt();
            int b = entrada.nextInt();
            
            double calculo = Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2);
            
            if (calculo > 0) {
                y += a + b;
            } else if (calculo < 0) {
                y += a + b - 5;
            } else {
                y += a - 2 * b;
            }
        }
                    
        System.out.println("y = " + y);
     }
}
```